# Error occurs when I attempt to run `npm install drizzle` (Truffle product)

Tags: truffle, drizzle

I am having an issue using Drizzle. When I run the command `npm install drizzle` I get the following error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably this? -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem.